# LocalDateTime Integration Testing

Tags: java, localdate, localdatetime

I am having assertion Error

Why the lenght of `second` is different in `toString()` and `DB Stored Value`

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path _embedded.positionsSnapshotDToes.linkTime doesn't match.
Expected: <[2022-11-09T10:01:03.152146400]>
  Actual: [2022-11-09T10:01:03.152146]
```

Using JPA to store entities basically I have following Pojo

```
@Column(name = "LINK_TIME")
    private LocalDateTime linkTime;
```

**Here is the test code**

```
@Test
shouldPassLinkTime()
{

        final LocalDateTime anyLinkTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        posSnapshotRepo.save(
                PositionsSnapshot.builder()
                        .linkTime(anyLinkTime)
                        .build()
        );

       SnapshotFilterDTO dto = SnapshotFilterDTO.builder()
                .build();

        given()
                .spec(correctCredentialsAndPortSpec)
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(MAPPER_HELPER.writeValueAsString(dto))
                .when()
                .post("service/unmatched")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .and().body("_embedded.positionsSnapshotDToes.linkTime", equalTo(Arrays.asList(anyLinkTime.toString())))


                .and().body("page.totalPages", equalTo(1))
                .and().body("page.totalElements", equalTo(1))
                .and().body("page.number", equalTo(0));
    }
```

Comment: When the time is converted to json it's probably not `toString()` that's called albeit I'd have to guess here. More likely an explicit formatter will be used that has less than nano-second precision.

Comment: How can I modify test case without changing JSON and JPA core implementation of the application

Comment: Well, I would try one of the following: 1) figure out the exact format used when creating the json and use that format on `anyLinkTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(theFormat))` 2) parse `_embedded.positionsSnapshotDToes.linkTime` to a proper `LocalDateTime` instance and compare with `anyLinkTime` directly.

Comment: You should avoid comparing the string representation of LocalDateTime, because actually both strings address the same time. Convert time string from JSON into another LocalDateTime instance and use .equals oder .compareTo

Comment: but how is it possible without using String, body() contains only String value

Comment: Are you trying to compare a value in hand to a value retrieved from database?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```java
// ...

.statusCode(200)
.log().ifValidationFails()
.and().body(LocalDateTime.parse(_embedded.positionsSnapshotDToes.linkTime), equalTo(Arrays.asList(anyLinkTime)))

//...
```

Comment: I've already tested it, having same error, java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path _embedded.positionsSnapshotDToes.linkTime doesn't match.
Expected: <[2022-11-09T11:06:23.986806700]>
  Actual: [2022-11-09T11:06:23.986807], most probably toString() is invoked internally

Comment: those are different  dates, you need to make your test mode tolerant, e.g. by applying LocalDateTime.truncateTo